# Rendering Spheres in SVG/Canvas

Tags: svg, webgl

I am getting ready to build some graphics that primarily involve rendering **semi-transparent spheres** (showing through an inner sphere of a smaller radius). I do need a 3D effect.

Can someone recommend what framework I should be using here? D3.JS, webgl, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

For a simple task it will be much easier to use declarative framework like http://www.x3dom.org/